# Reducir Imagen Android Studio

Tags: android, imagen

Quisiera reducir la calidad de una imagen que tomo de mi telefono para poder subirla a mi Base de Datos y poder descargarla sin tener que esperar mucho tiempo

Metodo para tomar la imagen y la comprime para poder subirla a la Base de Datos:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    int width=300;
    int heigth=240;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case COD_SELECCIONA:
                Bitmap originBitmap = null;
                Uri miPath = data.getData();
                image.setImageURI(miPath);

                convertphoto(miPath);


                break;

            case COD_FOTO:

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{path}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                                Log.i("Ruta de almacenamiento", "Path: " + path);
                            }
                        });

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) this.image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);


            break;
        }


    }
}
```

Metodo para comprimir la foto sacada de la galeria:

```
private void convertphoto(Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap originBitmap = null;
    //Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
   // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    InputStream imageStream;
    try {
        imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        originBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
    if (originBitmap != null) {
        this.image.setImageBitmap(originBitmap);
        Log.w("Image Setted in", "Done Loading Image");
        try {
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) this.image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            // Calling the background process so that application wont slow down

            //End Calling the background process so that application wont slow down
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("OOooooooooo", "exception");
        }
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Conversion Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // End getting the selected image, setting in imageview and converting it to byte and base 64
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? ¿Algún error que quieras que miremos?

Comment: no tengo ningun error es que al descargar la imagen se toma demasiado tiempo por la calidad de la imagen

Comment: Prueba a escalar el bitmap con la función createScaledBitmap en lugar de compress

Comment: y como lo puedo hacer? es que no conosco mucho del tema.

Comment: Sería llamar a la función después de obtener el bitmap en la línea: Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) this.image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); Bitmap imageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, false);

Comment: Gracias me trabaja perfecto

Comment: Me alegro. ¿Te lo pongo como respuesta y la aceptas?

Comment: si por supuesto con mucho gusto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de usar el método compress, prueba a usar la función Bitmap.createScaledBitmap. Sería llamar a la función después de obtener el bitmap:

```
Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) this.image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Bitmap imageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```